# Husky precommit does not run in Windows when using NVM

Tags: windows, git, githooks, nvm, husky

Followed all the Husky instructions, installed Husky, checked the husky directory was there, but when using nvm in windows, the pre-commit hook does not run. Also used the .huskyrc script suggested in their troubleshooting, but that too failed to run.

So seems an issue with Husky when running on Windows using NVM.

Have had to abort on this, has anyone else got this combination working?

Comment: If I said "yes" I'm not sure how helpful that'd be to you. Please may you share the husky config, commands, or other scripts relevant to the issue? Also share any errors that show.